# Unbolden and italicize headers in RMarkdown

Tags: html, r, r-markdown, markdown

I'd like to create subheaders that are not bold and italicized in an RMarkdown file. When I try manually use html tags like this

```
<h2 style="font-weight: normal;">*Header Example*</h2>
```

it gets indented as if it's a new paragraph. I do not want the subheader to be indented.

I have the setting in my YAML:

```
header-includes:
  - \setlength{\parindent}{30pt}
```

If I use the above approach, can I still control the line spacing between headers and paragraphs?

And there doesn't seem to be a difference between `h1` and `h2` tags with the above approach.

Answer (score 0):

I used the HTML \small element to make the text smaller and \textnormal to unbold.

```
# HEADER EXAMPLE $(\small{\textnormal{subheader example}})$
```

This keeps the subheader on the same line as the header. You can also easily italicize with *s.

```
# HEADER EXAMPLE $(\small{\textnormal{*subheader example*}})$
```

This way it doesn't get indented into a new line and you can still control the line spacing between headers and paragraphs.